# Applying animation on a view disables its childs ability to receive Drag Drop events

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a LinearLayout view that works perfectly to receive Drag and Drop events, until I applied the animation code below on its parent (RelativeLayout), the LinearLayout just receives ACTION_DRAG_STARTED and I return true, but it doesn't receive other events as ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED or ACTION_DROP, once I remove the animation below from its parent, the Drag Drop events works as exepected.

```
mOptions.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
mOptions.animate()
        .alpha(1.0f)
        .setDuration(150).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

         @Override
         public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                mOptions.clearAnimation();
                }
                });
```

Knowing that mOptions is the RelativeLayout that contains the LinearLayout that is set to receive Drap Drop events.

Knowing that mOptions by default is set to Gone visibility.

Comment: remove the `AnimatorListenerAdapter` - it is pointless as you are mixing up view and property animations

Comment: @pskink I need it as it starts another animation that hides another view.

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html - you are mixing up view and property animations, also read about `AnimatorSet#play*()` methods